# storing HIPAA data directly from ionic/angular mobile application front end

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework, hipaa

I have an Ionic app that gathers data from users in the form of a survey. The survey data needs to be stored in a HIPAA compliant manner.

I have discovered that box.com, google drive, AWS, and others are all decent options for HIPAA data.

MY QUESTION: what is the best way to post the data directly from the ionic frontend once the survey is complete? can any of these services create a small REST API? I am trying to avoid creating any sort of backend myself (besides a database).

Comment: **`"what is the best way to post the data"`** - Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "best" (e.g. most secure, most performant, easiest, etc...)? This is an interesting question, however it is a bit broad and opinionated which makes it a good candidate for **being closed as off topic** if you can't rewrite it to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I mean how do I directly post data from an ionic angular app to a HIPAA secure service? Do these services directly accept a post request from the application and put that data somewhere? as opposed to having to write a rest api backend that puts it into a database uri